# How to use sed to replace a string within a file with a another string surrounded by single quotes?

Tags: string, sed, replace, yaml, double-quotes

I have yaml file with content:

```
dummy:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

I want to use sed to replace `dummy` with `'dummy'`

I am trying:

```
sed -i '.yaml' 's/dummy/"'dummy'"/g' ~/Desktop/test.yaml
```

I get

```
"dummy":
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

I am getting a dummy string surrounded by double quotes as you can see...

IN FACT I want ***single quotes*** surrounding dummy

How do I get? :

```
'dummy':
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

Comment: YAML doesn't require quotes. This smells like an XY problem: Why must the key be enclosed in single quotes?

Comment: because my proprietary dataset has that main key surrounded by single quotes :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP adding solution too now.

```
sed "s#dummy#12345#"  Input_file
```

---

Following simple `sed` may help you here.

```
sed "s#dummy#'&'#"  Input_file
```

In case you want to save changes into Input_file itself by taking backup of Input_file then use following.

```
sed  -i.bak "s#dummy#'&'#"  Input_file
```

In `awk`:

```
awk '{sub("dummy","\047&\047")} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Becks, try to select answers as correct answer, by seeing your profile could say you hardly do that, if you select an answer correct then post will be considered as complete one, thanks and cheers.

Comment: will do sir. One last thing. If I wanted to replace dummy with 12345 how does your answer look like in that case?

Comment: @Becks, check my EDIT solution and let me know then.

Comment: that works Ravinder, ... I marked your answer. Thank you again